# Resize or Scroll the screen on Remote Debugging on Android with Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to use Remote Debugging Android Devices on chrome. But I can not resize my mobile screen fit to 100% or any on Chrome(PC).

On mobile it looks like

[image: Mobile Screen]

But on Chrome (PC) it looks like

[image: PC Screen]

Now the problem is : I can not either resize mobile screen on Chrome (PC) nor scroll to bottom (I can only scroll only if I can on mobile)

I tried by zoom in/out but it's not working. But I can see the remaining part by resizing window but I can not see on full size window.

I am using ***Chrome Version 50.0.2661.102 m on Windows 10 Pro(64bit), Android 5.1 on Moto G (1st Gen)***

**UPDATE :** Now I have updated chrome to ***Version 51.0.2704.84 m*** But still same problem

Comment: The developer tools shows UI like this when website is launched on chrome. Resize should work using the vertical divider line and scroll too. You might wanna restart system/ reinstall chrome.

Comment: @jitinsharma yeah, I did reinstall but problem is still same

Comment: Using Chrome 54 and exactly same issue. Looks like only the top half of the screen is displayed.
Resizing DevTools on the splitter has no impact on the display, in fact the Elements pane will overlay the phone screen if you resize it large enough then phone screen size never changes.

Comment: in a dual screen setup on a mac switching the window to another display a couple of times made the app window fit into the preview pane... 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you found a bug. Please file an issue on the [Chromium Issue Tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org) so the team can triage the problem and address it.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> several times it will resize automatically, I found this solution by chance:)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem debugging Ionic with Crosswalk, but I was able to resolve the issue by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and scrolling down.

Unfortunately, this changes the size of the text—but at least you can see all of the mobile screen.

Comment: yes, by this you are zooming out, not the solution for original question.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer it in best possible way.

When you resize the Chrome in Desktop Screen, try to resize the screen from divider screen between remote device and elements sections. Also use the resize from top of the Chrome as well if needed.

**You will find scrolling issue in Google website landing screen** (as in your case).

Try another website and check.

**Remote debugging requires your version of desktop Chrome to be newer than the version of Chrome for Android on your device. Try using Chrome Canary (Mac/Windows) or the Chrome Dev channel release (Linux) on desktop.**

See here for technical issue. [Android Remote Debugging Troubleshooting](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#troubleshooting)

Below are my observations for two tabs:

I have opened two different tabs in Chrome in my Android device.

Now in left side has active Google opened in tab 1 and in right side inactive StackOverFlow is there in tab 2.

[image: Screen 1 - Google 1]

In below screen, left side has inactive Google opened in tab 1 and in right side StackOverFlow is there in tab 2.

[image: Screen 2 - Stack Over Flow 1]

After scrolling StackOverFlow screen 
[image: Screen 2 - Stack Over Flow 2]

Individually screens look like below :

[image: Screen 3 - Google 1]

[image: Screen 4 - Stack Over Flow 1]

[image: Screen 4 - Stack Over Flow 2]

Please let me know if any issue is there. I am using **Android 5.1 on Moto E**